# regex to match strings not preceded by a bang

Tags: regex, bash

In bash, I am trying to match valid attributes that are present in an array. Attributes may be 'disabled' by preceding them with a bang (exclamation mark, !), in which case they must not be matched. I have this:

```
[[ ${TESTS[@]} =~ [^\!]match ]]
```

which will return true if the word 'match' is in TESTS and not preceded by a !.

It works, except when the word match is in the first position in the array. The problem is the regexp is saying *'match preceded by something that isn't a !'*. When it's the first item it is preceded by nothing and therefore does not match.

How do I modify the above to say *'match not preceded by !'* ?

From reading answers to other questions I have tried *(?<!!)match* but this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this re:

```
([^\!]|^)match
```

Example of usage:

```
$ [[ match =~ (^|[^\!])match ]] && echo matches || echo "doesn't match"
matches
$ [[ xmatch =~ (^|[^\!])match ]] && echo matches || echo "doesn't match"
matches
$ [[ '!match' =~ (^|[^\!])match ]] && echo match || echo "doesn't match"
doesn't match
```

In general, it would be also correct to use assertions here, but bash uses POSIX regular expressions and they know nothing about assertions. But with `grep` (GNU grep), or `perl`, or anything that supports PCRE you can do it:

```
$ echo match | grep -qP '(?<!!)match' && echo matches || echo "doesn't match"
matches
$ echo xmatch | grep -qP '(?<!!)match' && echo matches || echo "doesn't match"
matches
$ echo '!match' | grep -qP '(?<!!)match' && echo matches || echo "doesn't match"
doesn't match
```

Comment: @BlackVegetable: `if THING1; then THING2; else THING3; fi = THING1 && THING2 || THING3`

Comment: added explanation about '(?<!'. Please check it

Comment: ah, thanks. So I was on the right track then - I just didn't catch the fact that bash didn't dupport assertions. Thanks again.